# Express: How to send request response to the same page

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to send request response to home.ejs after getting response from request. I want to show loader on client side when request reaches to server and need to remove loader when request is completed. So for that I need to send request response to client side on same page i.e home.ejs from where I am sending post request. How do this?

app.js

```
app.post("/home", function(req, res){
    var snapshotname= req.body.snapshotname;
    data={"indices":"a","b","c"};
    url="url";
    method="POST";
    request.post({

        url: url,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'    
        }
    }, function(err, resp, body) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        res.render('home');
    })
})
```

home.ejs

```
<form action="/home" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="snapshotname" >
<button type="submit">Build</button>
```

Comment: I tried using connect-flash but req.flash() is not working for res.redirect().